# Viewport Meta Tag ruins CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a side project of mine where I have an HTML and CSS file. I started working on it from a mobile-first approach and things were looking good. But then I needed to make it a responsive design and added the following tag the CSS broke and did not work properly.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

```css
:root {
  --black: #191414;
  --green: #1DB954;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap') * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #181818;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 8fr 1fr;
  background-color: #181818;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
}

.music-img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 50px 50px;
}

.music-details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.music-name {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.album-name {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #8e8e8e;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#play,
#forward,
#backward,
#share,
#heart {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 20px 15px;
}

.list {
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* Firefox */
}

.list::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.footer {
  background-color: var(--black);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: center;
}

.song-name {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.song-band {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: #8e8e8e;
}

.song-detail {
  margin: 10px 50px;
}

#test {
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#home,
#search,
#library {
  width: auto;
  height: calc(100vh*0.05);
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.song-detail:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .footer {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Spotify</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="main">

      <div class="img">
        <img src="assets/album.jpg" class="music-img"></img>
      </div>

      <div class=music-details>

        <div class="music-name">
          Justice Beaver
        </div>

        <div class="album-name">
          The Office
        </div>

        <div class="play-items">

          <span><img src="assets/backward.png" id="backward"></img></span>
          <span><img src="assets/play.png" id="play"></img></span>
          <span><img src="assets/forward.png" id="forward"></img></span>
          <br>
          <span><img src="assets/heart.png" id="heart"></img></span>
          <span><img src="assets/share.png" id="share"></img></span>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="list">

      <div class="song-detail">

        <div class="song-name">Celebration</div>
        <div class="song-band">KOOL & THE GANG</div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer">

      <span><img src="assets/home.png" id="home"></img></span>
      <span><img src="assets/search.png" id="search"></img></span>
      <span><img src="assets/library.png" id="library"></img></span>


    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[Here is the image before adding the above tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bofOW.png)

[And here is the image after I added the above tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biNIV.png)

I and not sue what is wrong here. Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues in that code. First, you didn´t made the cassette img responsive, because you gave him a px size, then the img can´t resize, it´s static. If you want to make an img responsive, you have to use relative sizes, like "%" or "vw". Then you have to do the same with the icons, or at least add a media query for smaller devices and give them smaller sizes in px.
Same thing applies to the font size, it´s better to work with "em" or "rem", because they are relative sizes.

Then, i don´t know why you added this code

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .footer {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Because of the media query, this code only adds red color on devices that are bigger than 768, so tablets and cellphones won't apply
You should use it the simple way

```
  .footer {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

I think that´s a good start point to start making it responsive.
You can start by trying to make these changes.

```
.music-img {
  width: 15vw;
  height: 15vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  
}
.music-name {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.album-name {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #8e8e8e;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#play,
#forward,
#backward,
#share,
#heart {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 20px 15px;
}
  .footer {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

Then I think you would figure it out the rest.